# Magento: Allowing insecure content on https pages

Tags: magento-1.7, security, ssl

I'm facing an issue and I have no idea how to solve it. I use on another websites (which aren't developed in Magento) a jQuery script that gets an address once we type the zip code (a lot websites in Brazil, especially e-commerces, use that) but the url to retrieve all data, using ajax, is a "http" url and Magento blocks any requests made to that url once it doesn't use https.

Is there a way to make Magento allow this kind of http request even not using ssl? The feature of filling the user's address fields automatically is very important to make the user life easier, so, my customer really needs that.

Any ideas?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: The complaint about insecure content is a function of the user's web browser and rightly so to protect the end user. You don't allow insecure content, you figure out how to send it securely so the customer isn't at risk.

Answer (score 1):

On an SSL page any resource requested from a non SSl page is a security threat and Browsers are supposed to warn user.

I suggest you ask your other website provider to give you an alternate SSL URL this will solve the issue.

Other way is you call your site page using SSl which inturn communicates with the other site using Curl or some other protocol.Other site will respond to your Curl request.Which then is returned to your website visitor page from your php script.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the SSL/non-SSL part. It is about [JS same-origin-policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). What you could do is something like [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), but there are good reasons for the policy. Therefore you should find another solution, e.g. piping it through php, check the return and then if it is clean, send it back to the browser.

same-origin-policy in short:
AJAX is only allowed if you are requestion a page which has the same:

- protocol
- domain (same domain, NO suddomain)
- port

Answer (score 0):

If magento doesn't redirect `http` to `https`, even then your customer's web browser will block those requests (unless they add such exception to their browser settings?).

I would say the only sure way is to either disable SSL on the frontend or to edit the jquery script to send the request to the correct url. You can use `Mage::getUrl();` to output the url in a javascript variable. [See here for details on the `getUrl` function parameters.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters)